# Terraform : Import existing internet gateway and attach to vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

In terraform, we have an option to import the existing resources and we can manage through terraform.

I already have an IG in my region and I want to attach this to newly created VPC, what I have tried is

1. Imported the IG using `terraform import aws_internet_gateway.my_gw igw-c0a643a9`

2.In my configuration

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "my_gw" {
   vpc_id = module.vpc_dev.vpc_id
}
```

But this still try to create the new internet gateway so my question how to attach the existing IG into the newly created VPC

Comment: Can you share the plan output? And the output of `terraform state list`?

Comment: Ahh it's my bad it was actually modifying the resource , I have another configuration to create IG   thanks @ydaetskcoR for the debugging  approach

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use a data source to use the Internet Gateway :

```
data "aws_internet_gateway" "default" {
  internet_gateway_id = <the-id-of-your-internetgateway>
}
```

Comment: Both are fine but that's not the problem here